# Animated scroll / show hidden element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several questions around similar to this and I have tried all suggestions, to no avail.

I have a text area and a button. The button is initially hidden, but when the user types anything the button is shown.

In addition to this I want to scroll the page so that the button becomes visible. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#AddCommentEntryBox').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $('#AddCommentButton').show();
            $(window).scrollTop($('#AddCommentButton').position().bottom);
            //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
        } else {
            $('#AddCommentButton').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJQcM/

EDIT: better example - I need to scroll a parent element, not the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/sJQcM/3/

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot scroll to a hidden element.

Comment: The button is shown before I scroll. I got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/sJQcM/4/. This is enough but it won't work if the button isn't the bottom element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#AddCommentEntryBox').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $('#AddCommentButton').show();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('#AddCommentButton').offset().top})
        } else {
            $('#AddCommentButton').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sJQcM/1/)

You may want to exclude the backspace from this.

Your example may have also worked, the reason it didn't is because `.position()` gives only `.top` or `.left`. Bottom is not given (you have to calculate it yourself).

You can also use `.animate()` with `scrollTop` for smooth scrolling. In addition I recommend  you wait for the user to stop typing for a few seconds before scrolling, otherwise it will scroll down and the `textarea` will be only partially visible.

Comment: Thanks :) Why did you change position() to offset()?

Comment: [as you can see here in the console](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sJQcM/2/) the `offset()` gives you the position of the `element` in proportion to the `window`, while `position()` gives the position of the element in it's parent (a little different although here not so much, use whichever fits you better)

Comment: Hmm it doesn't quite work in my situation. In my page the body has overflow: hidden. I have a MainSection element that I need to scroll. At a minimum I need to simply scroll the parent div to the bottom. See edit.

Comment: I marked this as the answer. The technique is correct - now I just have to work on the scroll calculations specific to my page.